# How to change the space between one checkbox to another second checkbox horizontally?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I set the space between two checkboxes in PyQt? Currently, I have created two checkboxes and stored them in a QHBoxLayout, but the checkbox are too far apart in my GUI. (Image as shown below)
As you can see the checkbox is placed way too far apart. How do I shorten the space between the two checkboxes?

[image]

**CODE**

```
# Create Checkbox
showBuilding = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Buildings")
showBuilding.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 15, QtGui.QFont.Bold))

showRoad = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Roads")
showRoad.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 15, QtGui.QFont.Bold))


checkbox_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
checklay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(checkbox_container)
checklay.addWidget(showBuilding)
checklay.addWidget(showRoad)
```

Comment: I have edited the question to explain better

Comment: I am just trying to shorten down or decrease the space between "building" checkbox and "Road" checkbox. Base on the image you can see that the space between the checkbox is really wide apart. So I am trying to make the checkbox close ? I hope my reply answer any doubts

Comment: Only the "Road" Checkbox which is the QCheckbox on the right should be moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to continue using a QHBoxLayout then a possible solution is to establish a stretch to the right side and then set the distance using setSpacing():

```
checkbox_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
checklay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(checkbox_container)
checklay.addWidget(showBuilding)
checklay.addWidget(showRoad)
checklay.addStretch()
checklay.setSpacing(20)
```